# log4net with CloudWatch, cant see my logs in the console

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am using the example from [Here](https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet#apache-log4net)

My log4net configuration looks like this:

```
    <configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
<log4net debug="true">
  <appender name="AWS" type="AWS.Logger.Log4net.AWSAppender,AWS.Logger.Log4net">
    <LogGroup>MY_Logs</LogGroup>    
    <Region>us-west-2</Region>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-4timestamp [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="AWS" />
  </root>
</log4net>
</configuration>
```

my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="AWSProfilesLocation" value="awscredentials" />
    <add key="AWSRegion" value="us-west-2" />
  </appSettings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.8.0" newVersion="2.0.8.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

my awscredentials

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=[my_id]
aws_secret_access_key=[my_access_key]
```

here is the debug info on my console app:

```
  log4net: Configuration update mode [Merge].
log4net: Logger [root] Level string is [ALL].
log4net: Logger [root] level set to [name="ALL",value=-2147483648].
log4net: Loading Appender [AWS] type: [AWS.Logger.Log4net.AWSAppender,AWS.Logger
.Log4net]
log4net: Setting Property [LogGroup] to String value [MY_Logs]
log4net: Setting Property [Region] to String value [us-west-2]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=F
alse]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=F
alse]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%-4timestamp [%th
read] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline]
log4net: Converter [timestamp] Option [] Format [min=4,max=2147483647,leftAlign=
True]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign
=False]
log4net: Converter [thread] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=Fa
lse]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [] ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign
=False]
log4net: Converter [level] Option [] Format [min=5,max=2147483647,leftAlign=True
]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=
False]
log4net: Converter [logger] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=Fa
lse]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=
False]
log4net: Converter [ndc] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False
]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ - ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlig
n=False]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=F
alse]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=F
alse]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.PatternLayout]
log4net: Creating repository for assembly [AWSSDK.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture
=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604]
log4net: Assembly [AWSSDK.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken
=885c28607f98e604] Loaded From [C:\Users\stal\documents\visual studio 2017\Proje
cts\ConsoleApp9\ConsoleApp9\bin\Debug\AWSSDK.Core.dll]
log4net: Assembly [AWSSDK.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken
=885c28607f98e604] does not have a RepositoryAttribute specified.
log4net: Assembly [AWSSDK.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken
=885c28607f98e604] using repository [log4net-default-repository] and repository
type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: repository [log4net-default-repository] already exists, using repositor
y type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: Creating repository for assembly [AWSSDK.CloudWatchLogs, Version=3.3.0.
0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604]
log4net: Assembly [AWSSDK.CloudWatchLogs, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, Publ
icKeyToken=885c28607f98e604] Loaded From [C:\Users\stal\documents\visual studio
2017\Projects\ConsoleApp9\ConsoleApp9\bin\Debug\AWSSDK.CloudWatchLogs.dll]
log4net: Assembly [AWSSDK.CloudWatchLogs, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, Publ
icKeyToken=885c28607f98e604] does not have a RepositoryAttribute specified.
log4net: Assembly [AWSSDK.CloudWatchLogs, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, Publ
icKeyToken=885c28607f98e604] using repository [log4net-default-repository] and r
epository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: repository [log4net-default-repository] already exists, using repositor
y type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: Created Appender [AWS]
log4net: Adding appender named [AWS] to logger [root].
log4net: Hierarchy Threshold []
```

I dont see anything out of the ordinary in the debug info.

Looking at my aws cloudwatch console, I do not see the group My_Logs.

I have permissions to view/write to cloudwatch.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar issue, my log4net logs were not writing to CloudWatch even though it looked like the configuration was correct. I was able to find the issue (in my case, I was missing some configuration settings) by enabling the logging feature of AWS.Logger.Log4net by adding the following to the appender node

```
<LibraryLogFileName>c:\logs\awslog.txt</LibraryLogFileName>
```

So in your case the new configuration section would look like

```
<appender name="AWS" type="AWS.Logger.Log4net.AWSAppender,AWS.Logger.Log4net">
 <LogGroup>MY_Logs</LogGroup>    
 <Region>us-west-2</Region>
 <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
   <conversionPattern value="%-4timestamp [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline" />
 </layout>
 <LibraryLogFileName>c:\logs\awslog.txt</LibraryLogFileName>
</appender>
```

Just make sure to check the log file quickly, in my case it gained size quite rapidly.  Hopefully the error messages in the log file will point you to the issue.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Adding LibraryLogFileName allowed me to quickly trace and resolve my issue, which turned out to be IAM permissions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html):

> In order to embed the configuration data in the .config file the section name must be identified to the .NET config file parser using a configSections element. The section must specify the log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler that will be used to parse the config section.

Which is missing in your config file. So add the following:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>
```

Comment: that didnt work, I updated the question with my new .config file